# how to send multiple message using a TCP socket in C# without closing the socket connection?

Tags: c#, sockets

i need to send multiple messages on a TCP sockect connection using C# is it possible?
if so, how to do it?

Comment: Can you put a bit more effort/detail/code into your question please.

Answer (score 5):

A TCP socket is just a stream; you simply **keep writing to it**. I *suspect* the problem here is how to break such a stream into discreet messages - for that you need to add some kind of logical *framing* into your stream. Obviously, the one thing you ***cannot*** do is "read until you get to the end of the stream", as that *doesn't apply* if sending multiple messages down the same socket.

For text-based messages this often means "write each message followed by a newline as a separator" (and "read until you get a newline"). For binary, it almost always takes the form of a length-prefix in some way. For example, a simple protocol might include 4 bytes before each message as the little-endian 32-bit integer representation of the length of the following message, so when writing it is "write the length, write the payload" - and when reading it is "read the length, read that many bytes, process that message" (note: 4 bytes is not necessarily a good way to do this, as it can't handle very large payloads - whether this is a problem depends on the data you want to send).

In both cases, because *network* packets are largely unrelated to how many times you call `Write` / `Send`, your reading code will need to buffer and loop.

See also http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html which has more thoughts on this topic.